# Inserting libraries or plug-ins into Microsoft Office apps for Mac

Tags: macos, plugins, frameworks, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to write a plugin for Office on Mac to match some functionality I have on Windows. I've been working with Word 2011 for Mac to create a PoC. I can get my library loaded into Word in various ways, but I'd really like something clean and (at least somewhat) supported.

I've discovered a WordPDE.plugin inside the app bundle, but DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES reveals that the plugin is never loaded under typical operation (Start app, create doc, type content, save doc, quit app.)  I placed a dummy plugin beside WordPDE.plugin only to have it ignored by Word.

I also see that the Office apps include a MicrosoftComponentPlugin.framework but the information reported by class-dump doesn't help determine how to write a "Microsoft Component Plugin" nor how it might actually get loaded.

Ultimately, I can get my library into Word by asking dyld to do it, or by modifying load commands in the executable, but I'd much prefer going a cleaner route with some kind of plugin. Is there anyone with any information about how Word for Mac loads and uses this plugin and/or the mentioned framework?

Comment: Any solution you found to add plugin for MSOffice app in MACOS?